# Java math not returning expected value

Tags: java, math, random, integer, modulo

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_primality_test, if a^(n-1) does not equal 1 mod n, then the number is a composite number. As we know, 3 is a prime number while 9 is not. My Java skills are very outdated and I'm likely forgetting something very simple. Keep in mind this is only the beginning of the  test as well, not the full implementation of the test. The example code below returns false for both numbers, while only 9 should return false.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LucasTest
{
    private static int n;
    private static boolean primeResult;

    public static int randInt(int min, int max) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

        return randomNum;
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int num)
    {
        int a = randInt(2, num - 1);
        int b = num - 1;
        double c = Math.pow(a,b);

        if (c != (1.0 % num)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer:");

        Scanner pNum = new Scanner(System.in);

        n = pNum.nextInt();

        primeResult = isPrime(n);

        System.out.println("Number is likely prime?: " + primeResult);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you traced through the code in an IDE debuggers?

Comment: I'm not sure I would trust `Math.pow` in this context, as opposed to an actual integer power mod n method (which you'd have to write yourself).

Comment: I'm using BlueJ at the moment Jim, and the debugger doesn't seem to output anything useful for me.

Comment: I don't know what you expect 1 mod num to be. and how you check a prime without any loop? I guess you have to study the formula again.

Comment: Yep, realized the error there. Product of a 1 AM work. Also, I stated earlier it was only the very beginning portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the test in your isPrime method.

Change

```
if (c != (1.0 % num))
```

to

```
if ((c % num) != 1.0)
```

What you are doing is first taking 1.0 mod num, which is 1 and then checking if c is not equal to 1 (which it never will be except for num=1).

What we need to do is compute c mod num and then check if that is 1.

I tested your code with this change, and it correctly identifies 3, 7, and 13 as prime and identifies 9 and 15 as composite.

**Note:** There are two checks in that theorem and you have only implemented the first.  It is possible that you will return a true statement for composite numbers randomly because of this.  Also, the theorem states that *some* a must exist for the given number, but not that the conditions are true for *every* a, thus even with both checks, as you are testing a random a, you may randomly identify a prime number as composite.

To fully implement the theorem you would have to implement the second condition and then check every a in the interval (1,n).  If both conditions hold for any given a, return true (and don't bother checking the other a's), else return false.  Of course, the second condition is harder to implement as you must find the prime factors of (n-1).

Comment: Edit: Your last edit has corrected my silly error. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode in the page you shared says.

Input: n > 2, an odd integer to be tested for primality; k, a parameter that determines the accuracy of the test

Output: prime if n is prime, otherwise composite or possibly composite;
determine the prime factors of n−1.

```
LOOP1: repeat k times:

  pick a randomly in the range [2, n − 1]

  if a^(n-1) != 1 (mod n) then return composite
  otherwise 
     LOOP2: for all prime factors q of n−1:
        if a^((n-1)/q) != 1 (mod n) 
           if we did not check this equality for all prime factors of n−1 
              then do next LOOP2
           otherwise return prime
        otherwise do next LOOP1
return possibly composite.
```

Comment: Question already answered, and I'm fully aware of this, as I was basing the bare beginning off of this. I have since progressed past this now. Thank you, however.